# How can I use findBy method with multiple or(|) and(&) operators?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

For the below sql script I can write the below method(findByCreateDateBetweenorRRNOrCurrency).

```
Page<CustomObject> findByCreateDateBetweenAndPoutRrnOrPoutPassport(Pageable pageable, Date startDate, Date endDate, String RRN, String Currency);
```

where

```
createDate between CONVERT(Datetime, '2018-06-29 16:17:15.763', 120) and CONVERT(Datetime, '2018-06-30 16:17:15.763', 120) 
or RRN='N0000002628607' or currency = 'AZN'
```

**How can I write findBy method for the below sql script?**

```
where 
createDate between CONVERT(Datetime, '2018-06-29 16:17:15.763', 120) and CONVERT(Datetime, '2018-06-30 16:17:15.763', 120) 
and (RRN='N0000002628607' or currency = 'AZN')
```

Comment: Clearly JPQL has no CONVERT method ...

Comment: I you have the SQL available, use the Native query on your @Query method.